# How do i add or subtract current seconds to a count down timer?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how you can make it so that you can add or subtract time from your current time. For example subtract or add 5 seconds.

```
var count = 1000;

var counter = setInterval(timer, 10); //10 will  run it every 100th of a second

function timer()
{
    if (count <= 0)
    {
        clearInterval(counter);
        alert('De bom is ontploft. Kaboom!')
        return;
     }
     count--;
     document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=count / 100;
```

}

Comment: You want to subtract `5` or add `5` to `count`  or what?

Comment: Yes, i want to add or subtract 5 to count.

Comment: For adding `count += 5` for subtracting `count -= 5`

Comment: You can't return before you increment `count`. Anything after `return` won't execute